# Android quiz message alert

Tags: android

Hi im creating a quiz application. I want to add a function in my submit button where if the user didnt pick any answer in the radiobutton there will be a message saying "select an answer please" Here is the code

```
  public void onClickNext(View view) {
    String level = getIntent().getExtras().getString("level");
    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
    db.getQuestByLevel(level, qnum);

    RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.questionAndAnswers);
    RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    if (corAnswer != null && corAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase((String) answer.getText())) {
        score++;
        Log.d("answer", "Your score" + score);
    }
    if (qnum <= 5) {

    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    txtQuestion.setText(db.question);
    rda.setText(db.optionA);
    rdb.setText(db.optionB);
    rdc.setText(db.optionC);
    rdd.setText(db.optionD);
    corAnswer = db.answer;
    qnum++;
    rdgrp.clearCheck();
}
```

}

Comment: and...I suppose something is not working? If yes, in what way?

Comment: its when i leave the radiogroup empty(notchecked) then i click the submit button

Comment: and then what happens? or does not happen?

Comment: Thought so. "RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());" What is "answer" if there is no checked radiobutton to be found?

Comment: so.. should i remove it or ?

Comment: please take a look at my answer - I think you wanted to remind the user to select a radiobutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line

```
RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

if no `RadioButton` was checked, `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` will return "-1" and as there is no View with that id, "answer" will be `null`.

So you could do the following

```
if (answer == null)
{
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "select an answer please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // nothing more to do here so 
    return;
}
if (corAnswer!= null && corAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase((String) answer.getText())
{
    // continue as before
}
```

Comment: thanks really helped me a lot !